# Force File Download in Safari

Tags: php, file, safari, http-headers

I am trying to make a file downloadable in Safari.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment");
header ("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

It works fine in FF but in Safari I get a 0kb file.

I think I there is something wrong in the header I am sending.
What could be the error?

Comment: Your script has serious security troubles...

Comment: Old, but dangerous nonetheless! This allows traversing of parent directories (`../`), enabling downloading of PHP files, config files, and more outside the web/public folder!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This.

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
header('content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
readfile($file);
?>
```

**Beware:** Relying on `$_GET['file']` without any sanitation or restrictions is very dangerous. Can be used to compromise the entire server application!